# Why do I get a 'Expression type '(_) -> _' is ambiguous without more context' error

Tags: swift, mvvm, closures

I'm adapting an [example of MVVM](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-architecture-patterns-ecba4c38de52#.jmk9xuefn) to my app and I'm getting an 'Expression type '(_) -> _' is ambiguous without more context' error even though I've structured my code exactly like the example. Here's the relevant code (Swift 2.3):

The view controller:

```
class CalculatorViewController: UIViewController, CalculatorViewModelDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, DismissalDelegate {

  let dataManager = LiftEventDataManager()

  @IBOutlet weak var liftNameButtonView: UIView!
  @IBOutlet weak var liftNameButton: UIButton!
  @IBOutlet weak var repsLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var repetitionsField: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var weightLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var weightLiftedField: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var oneRepMaxField: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var units: UILabel!

  var weightLifted: String {
    return weightLiftedField.text!
  }

  var repetitions: String {
    return repetitionsField.text!
  }

  var viewModel: CalculatorViewModelProtocol! {
    didSet {

// This is were I get the 'Expression type '(_) -> _' is ambiguous without more context' error
      self.viewModel.weightLiftedDidChange = { [unowned self] viewModel in
        self.weightLiftedField.text = viewModel.greeting
      }
    }
  }

 override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    let viewModel = CalculatorViewModel(delegate: self)

    self.viewModel = viewModel

    weightLiftedField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didChangeWeightLifted), forControlEvents: .EditingDidEndOnExit)
   }

  func didChangeWeightLifted() {
    viewModel!.weightLifted = self.weightLifted
    }
  }
```

And my view model:

```
protocol CalculatorViewModelProtocol: class {

    weak var delegate: CalculatorViewModelDelegate? { get set }
    var liftName: String? { get set }
    var weightLifted: String? { get set }
    var repetitions: String? { get set }
    var oneRepMax: String? { get set }
    var units: String? { get set }
    var date: String? { get set }

    // the type is clearly defined here
    var weightLiftedDidChange: ((CalculatorViewModelProtocol) -> ())? { get set }

    var repetitionsDidChange: ((CalculatorViewModelProtocol) -> ())? { get set }
    //var oneRepMaxDidChange: ((CalculatorViewViewModel) -> ()) { get set }
    func calculateOneRepMax(weightLifted: Double, repetitions: UInt8)
}

class CalculatorViewModel: CalculatorViewModelProtocol, LiftEventDataManagerDelegate {

    let calculator = CalculatorBrain()

    private let dataManager = LiftEventDataManager()

    var liftName: String?
    var weightLifted: String?
    var repetitions: String?
    var oneRepMax: String?
    var units: String?
    var date: String?
    var weightLiftedDidChange: ((CalculatorViewModelProtocol) -> ())?
    var repetitionsDidChange: ((CalculatorViewModelProtocol) -> ())?

    func changeWeightLifted(weight: String) {
        weightLifted = weight
    }
}
```

Xcode seems to be telling me that it can't infer the type of `self.viewModel.weightLiftedDidChange` but I've specified the type in my `viewModel` class.

There are a lot of threads about this error but I haven't found one that has helped and I've scoured Apple's documentation but, no joy.

Comment: What type is `viewModel.greeting`? Sometimes this error can happen if something inside the closure has an unrelated error (just a bug with the way error reporting works).

Comment: @jtbandes, boy do I feel dumb. 'greeting' is from the example I was using and it has nothing to do with my app. I must have stared at this for 2 hours and I didn't notice. It turns out that if I use an actual variable that I have in my app (self.weightLiftedField.text = viewModel.weightLifted) the error goes away. :-) Thanks.

Comment: Good to hear ;-)  If you can reduce this to a very simple test case, I would recommend filing a bug at https://bugs.swift.org. The error message you got is very bad. (You can use the `DiagnosticsQoI` label)

Comment: Good idea. I'll do that.